# Efficient way to CHECK UNIQUE on two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 which has columns for two countries, let's call them CountryA and CountryB.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AgreementParticipants
(
    AgreementParticipantsID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    CountryA CHAR(3) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Country (CountryCode),
    CountryB CHAR(3) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Country (CountryCode)
);
```

Note: the table has been simplified for the example, however the important thing is that is always defines a bilateral relationship between two entities. It just so happens that in this case it's two countries.

*Typical data*:

```
1 AUS USA
2 USA NZL
```

*Business rules*:

1. There will always be exactly two counties.
2. The two countries can be in either order. There is no significance to position A or B.
3. Each combination of two countries must be unique to the table. Therefore, AUS USA is considered the same as USA AUS.
4. The two countries will never be the same.

**The question**:

What is the most efficient way to enforce the uniqueness constraint?

Currently, I've considered using a trigger or a convoluted check constraint, but both solutions feel inelegant so I'd like some input from the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with two conditions.  The first is a unique index (or constraint):

```
create unique index AgreementParticipants_CountryA_CountryB on AgreementParticipants(CountryA, CountryB)
```

The second is a condition that `CountryA` is less than `CountryB`:

```
check (CountryA < CountryB)
```

If the countries could be the same, then the condition would be `<=`.

One disadvantage of this approach is that, on insert, `CountryA` has to be less than `CountryB` (alphabetically first).  Otherwise, this generates an error.

An alternative approach uses computed columns and a unique index:

```
alter table AgreementParticipants
    add Country1 as (case when CountryA < CountryB then CountryA else CountryB end);

alter table AgreementParticipants
    add Country2 as (case when CountryA < CountryB then CountryB else CountryA end);

create unique index AgreementParticipants_Country1_Country2 on AgreementParticipants(Country1, Country2);
```

The advantage of this approach is that the countries can be inserted into the table in either order.

Comment: @MarkyMark . . . I revised the answer to give two solutions.  The first would require that the pair be AUS USA.  The second can handle the pairs in either order.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'll give your solution a try and see how I go.

Comment: Gordon, I'm checking your's as the accepted answer as it works and has what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints like:

`CHECK ( CountryA < CountryB )`
`UNIQUE ( CountryA, CountryB )`

is one way to do it

Another way is to add computed columns like:

`CREATE TABLE t2 (CountryA ..., CountryB ...
                 ,least_country as LEAST( CountryA, CountryB )
                 ,greatest_country as GREATEST( CountryA, CountryB ) )`

and then put a unique constraint on the new columns. Not sure whether SQLServer supports LEAST, but it is easy to create one if it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's great second alternative can be simplified by to one computed column, by projecting a unique 'hash' per combination of `CountryA, CountryB`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AgreementParticipants ADD CountryProjection AS
CASE WHEN CountryA < CountryB 
          THEN CountryA + '-' + CountryB 
          ELSE CountryB + '-' + CountryA
        END;

ALTER TABLE dbo.AgreementParticipants ADD CONSTRAINT U_AgreementParticipants 
UNIQUE (CountryProjection);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b898a/1)

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to SQL Fiddle, what a useful site!